# Javascript wipes out contents of the second page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML files: `index.html` and `Page2.html`.
I have a button in `index.html` page which is called `WWW_onclick()`.
As you see below, this function opens `Page2.html` and writes "hello".
Problem is this function wipes out the original `Page2.html` and only writes "hello".

Is there a way to keep the content of the `Page2.html` and add additional text, image, or ... in it?

```
function WWW_onclick()
{
   document.location.href = "Page2.html";
   document.write("hello");
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280750/how-to-change-content-after-page-is-loaded-js

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

It will clear your HTML.

You should use `innerHTML`

Example:

```
document.getElementById("your-id").innerHTML = "hello";
```

Comment: I tried this but it only opened the page2  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
            document.location.href = "Page2.html";
document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = "hello";


    });

});

Comment: @HamidNasr Edit your OP and tell us what you have tried.